# including Javascript into Wordpress 3.8

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i'd like to include the virtual keyboard into my wordpress site but it doesn't function.

I use this howto include: http://archive09.linux.com/feature/134811
and i use this keyboard: http://freecode.com/projects/jsvk

of course i also add some plugins in wordpress and search google, but i'm not a devleoper :)

Can you give me some tipps?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

upload the file into your themes js folder or make one......

in your themes functions php file

```
$url= get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'js/filename.js'; //input whatever path to file actually is.
function add_keyboard() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'keyboard', $url);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_keyboard' );
```